# Várias aplicações consumindo um mesmo banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, arquitetura-de-software, nosql, cloud

Hoje tenho uma aplicação que utiliza de um banco de dados (MongoDB), porém tenho poucos usuários ainda e como sabemos é muito difícil ter uma aplicação que faça sucesso e acumule muitos usuários.

Pensando nisso estou planejando criar uma segunda aplicação que irá utilizar esse mesmo banco, compartilhando os dados, pois as duas utilizam praticamente os mesmos, porém, com finalidades diferentes.

De forma simplificada, um usuário que criou uma conta em minha aplicação A, conseguiria utilizar a aplicação B sem fazer um novo cadastro e utilizaria inclusive dos seus dados que já foram cadastrados.

Posso estar errado, mas se as duas aplicações ficarem em pequeno a médio porte, acredito que não terei problemas, mas e se eu tiver a 'sorte' dessas aplicações se popularizarem, quais tipos de problemas eu poderia ter? Essa arquitetura pode resultar em graves efeitos colaterais? Isso seria uma economia 'porca'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tudo pode se você fizer a aplicação do jeito correto dando esta funcionalidade.

Se não tiver um bom motivo para manter isto junto não mantenha. Não tem economia de fato. Você está dizendo que é outra aplicação, então porque deveria usar o mesmo banco de dados? Provavelmente nem tem as mesmas necessidades. Se tiver um motivo eve ser bem justificado, deve conseguir demonstrar ganho. Se não consegue não faça.

Depois de ver todo tipo de abuso em linguagens de programação agora estou vendo abusos em bancos de dados. Eu já respondi algumas vezes aqui no site mesmo sobre a desnecessidade da adoção de NoSQL na maioria dos cenários. As pessoas adotam porque parece mais fácil e mais flexível. E a pessoa nem imagina o monte de problema e dificuldade que terá em certos cenários. O abuso que ando vendo é as pessoas "socarem" todo tipo de dado lá no banco como se fosse a casa da mãe Joana só porque o banco de dados deixa. Isso sim é algo porco. A maior parte da adoção do NoSQL que vejo por aí é preguiça de fazer certo. Não posso falar se é seu caso, só você sabe (espero).

Se tiver "sorte" e conseguir um uso explosivo, o menor dos seus problemas será esse, é o fato de não entender o que precisa fazer para escalar a aplicação, e isso só uma pessoa especializada e que conheça seu cenário poderá ajudar. Quando tiver um uso muito grande poderá repensar o que está fazendo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, me esclareceu bastante a mente. Eu devo manter junto mesmo, refletindo aqui eu poderia dizer que é inclusive uma só aplicação, mas eu irei criar 'duas marcas' assim dizendo, uma será para parte de gestão e a outra para o usuário poder entrar em contato direto com os clientes. Como se fosse controle de estoque e a outra parte um E-commerce. Eu iria ter muito dado duplicado caso fizesse separado.

Comment: Este tipo de software parece mias adequando quando é transacional. Aí usando NoSQL ou abandona esse requisito e todo tipo de problema pode ocorrer ou recriar o sistema de transações na aplicação, o que praticamente todo mundo faz errado, além de dar uma trabalho monstro. NoSQL é para aplicações que não são transacionais.